# PYLINT - Lots of "missing final newline" messages

Tags: python, pylint

I'm new to pylint, but in one of my analyses, I'm getting LOADS of "missing-final-newline" messages. I am literally getting one error for every line in my python file.

It is strange that this error comes up for every line, given what the message is implying.

As I mentioned, it's affecting every line, but for the sake of being exhaustive, here's some code that is generating errors:

```
from UcsSdk import UcsHandle
import logging, json, os

def getucswwpns(module):

    results = {}
```

I'll post some of these messages, but it's kind of pointless.

```
C:  1, 0: Final newline missing (missing-final-newline)
C:  2, 0: Final newline missing (missing-final-newline)
C:  3, 0: Final newline missing (missing-final-newline)
C:  4, 0: Final newline missing (missing-final-newline)
C:  5, 0: Final newline missing (missing-final-newline)
C:  6, 0: Final newline missing (missing-final-newline)
C:  7, 0: Final newline missing (missing-final-newline)
C:  8, 0: Final newline missing (missing-final-newline)
C:  9, 0: Final newline missing (missing-final-newline)
C: 10, 0: Final newline missing (missing-final-newline)
C: 11, 0: Final newline missing (missing-final-newline)
C: 12, 0: Final newline missing (missing-final-newline)
C: 13, 0: Final newline missing (missing-final-newline)
C: 14, 0: Final newline missing (missing-final-newline)
C: 15, 0: Final newline missing (missing-final-newline)
C: 16, 0: Final newline missing (missing-final-newline)
C: 17, 0: Final newline missing (missing-final-newline)
```

See what I mean?

Comment: It maybe your editor?

Comment: Maybe pylint expects a different EOL character than your editor uses?

Comment: There is probably no newline after the {}. Do an od -c on the file and have a look.  If you never hit enter after the `}`  then in a lot of editors, when the file is saved, will not add a newline to that last line, which I believe is correct behavior.

Comment: For some reason Atom added a \r to the end of every line, instead of the usual \n it was adding to all other documents. Looks like I'll be going back to my old editor....Thanks Tim! Feel free to put up an answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1):

I found this is caused by having incorrect line endings for the platform.

In Notepad++ go Edit->EOL conversion and change to the OS you are on.